# Why were US states named after Aboriginal American tribes?

Tags: united-states

Americans wanted to implement manifest destiny and own the land from the Atlantic to the Pacific.  Why would they name territories and states after Aboriginal American tribes?  For instance, why were North Dakota, South Dakota, and Kentucky named that way?

From the Americans' point of view, this would seem to do two things that are distinctly negative:

- It chips away at American influence.  Names influence power and the perception of power.  If Americans name a state "Gray Boulder" or "Madison", that gives Americans better influence than if they name it after an Aboriginal American tribe.
- It would seem to discourage settlement in those areas!  Why would Americans leave from New York to settle in a remote area named after people who they are fighting, and who are characterized as hostile and savage?

I also don't buy the fact that they would need to do this to co-opt or placate the Aboriginal Americans in that area.  I think it would have been obvious to all parties that the Americans had the military power and numbers to achieve their goals.

Comment: In most cases, the states weren't named after the tribes.  They were named after what *other people* called those tribes.

Comment: For the same reason housing-projects (often) are named after the plants, trees or animals that had to be "removed" to make room for it?

Comment: @Bobson: Fair point.  Question still stands though.

Comment: @BaardKopperud: I guess that's possible.  It's sort of the auto-pilot naming system.  I will definitely re-assert though that naming a _state_ is a huge thing.  I can see naming a creek after someone without analyzing the political ramifications of it for weeks.  But the name of a _state_ is a huge thing.

If it was auto-pilot naming, then perhaps my question can be reworded to basically ask if Americans were foolish from a political point of view to not adopt a more Americanized naming system.  Because in retrospect it seems that it would have been.

Comment: @Anonymous - I had another thought on this: you really need to define what you mean by "American" in this context. More English (like Virginia and New York)? More French (like Louisiana and Detroit)? More Spanish (Like Florida and Montana)?  Most large features were named before America had a cultural identity that you'd recognize as American.

Comment: doesn't this question belong to history SE

Answer (score 13):

As DA. says, this question *vastly* oversimplifies things.  However, there's actually a relatively simple answer: **States were named after the Territories they were formed from.**

Of course, then you have the next question: Why were the Territories named after Native American tribes?  And the answer to that is that often, they weren't.  Or at least, they were named after what one group called another group, rather than what the group called itself.

For example, here's North/South Dakota:

1. Louisiana is named after King Louis XIV (French).  When the US bought it, they named the whole thing the Louisiana Territory.
2. When part of it became the state of Louisiana, the rest of it became the [Missouri Territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missouri_Territory), after the Missouri river, which was a name [adapted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missouri#Etymology) by the French settlers from the name which the Illinois-speaking Native Americans called the Siouan-speaking tribe in the area.  (The [Missouria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missouria) called themselves *Niúachi* in Siouan, but our name is derived from *Wimihsoorita* in Illinois).
3. When Missouri became a state, a chunk of the rest of the Purchase became the [Nebraska Territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebraska_Territory).  Again, it was [named for a river](http://www.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~neycha/history/nebchange.htm), in this case the *Nebrathka* or *Nebraskier* river, which was the name in the [Otoe's language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otoe_tribe).
4. Finally, the Dakotas *were* named for the [Native Americans in the area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakota_people), although it wasn't what any of the tribes there called themselves.  Instead, it comes from the word for "ally", which is how they referred to each other.

Corollary to all this, **names have sticking power**.  If you've been calling the area where the Dakota people live "the Dakota's land" for 50 years, then when you go settle there you're settling in "Dakota land".  That's what people further away will know it as, because the name has had time to spread.  You may found your new city based on a name that's more familiar to you (your name, or a national hero, or a descriptive name, etc), but when you're referring to the general area, you refer to it by the name that most people will know it by.  (This is the same idea where you might say that you're from "New York City" or "Eastern US" to someone from France, but the "Lower East Side" or a specific street to someone from Brooklyn.)

Names like Louisiana, New England, and Virginia are exceptions to this, because they were named either by people overseas (and thus didn't care what the locals already called it) or by newly arrived explorers who had yet to actually establish communication with the locals.

I'll also point out that very few names are based on what the tribes actually called themselves.  Instead, they're almost all based on what they called each other.  Further reading on that can be found in [Wikipedia's page on Exonyms vs Endonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exonym_and_endonym) (the names people give each other vs the names they give themselves).  To the best of my (admittedly unresearched) knowledge, few (if any) "native american" names are endonyms.  Every single one I know about, except for small towns or buildings that have been founded or renamed in the last ~100 years, is based on what some other group called the locals, or a corruption thereof.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation of that history.  Perhaps the question can be rephrased to ask if, from a purely political point of view, Americans could have, and should have, been more aggressive if using Americanized names.

I'm having a little trouble believing they couldn't have named North Dakota something else and still had people go along with it.

Comment: @Anonymous what do you feel they did wrong with calling it "North Dakota"? At the time it was part of the Dakota Territory, so from a purely branding standpoint, it was already a known name.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. This is a political question. Political groups tend to name things after themselves and in their own language. I think this is a pretty standard tool in terms of political power. I have never understood why the Americans didn't carry this out with things like the states. I feel like they could have, and I'm just not sure why they chose not to. In terms of the Dakota Territory, the question then falls back to why they named the territory that. The context for the question remains the same.

Comment: @Anonymous - `Political groups tend to name things after themselves and in their own language` - Do you have any proof to back this up?  I don't think this is actually the case, with the exception of modern totalitarian governments.  Starting with a mistaken premise will cause strange results.

Comment: @Bobson Fair question.  I cant' say I do, so I'll have to claim this seems to be an observation.  I've also seen quotes that make this very claim.  I believe it's a well understood point.  Unfortunately, I don't have surveys on hand that prove this actually happens 90%+ when things are named.

And if this hypothesis is incorrect, then again, perhaps the question could be rephrased to ask if it would not have been better for the Americans to have adhered to this principle.

Comment: @Anonymous - Look at the place names in England  - many names predate Christian England and even Roman England.  Why is Lancaster still named after a Roman Fort? Aside from pronunciation place names don't change much over time.

Answer (score 8):

This question's premise is oversimplifying and generalizing the relationships between Europeans and Native Americans over a huge span of time. There's a ton of history here with a lot of nuance.

The reason so many places in the US are named after Native American nations and/or named after the original Native American term is that we shared this land for hundreds of years. Sometimes quite peacefully, sometimes not.

There was no out-right "we must take all of this land" mantra. It was a slow process piece-by-piece. Sometimes legitimately, often not.

Comment: Yes, I think pretty much everything you say is true.  However, I think the validity of my question still stands. Even if Americans lived peacefully with certain tribes for a certain period of time in certain areas, why would they name states, or anything else, after those tribes? The explicit and implicit frame of my question is that _they simply didn't have to_, and furthermore, it would have been better for their interests if they hadn't.

For instance, we get along fine with Poland. But we don't name anything after Poland, and especially not _states_! The naming of a state is _huge_!

Comment: 'better for their interests' isn't very specific, though. There was no one particular set of interests spanning those many hundreds of years. People name locations based on what people call those locations. It makes sense that a lot of locations had names like "Dakota land" already.

Comment: I can only refer back to my assertion that whoever names something has power over it, and power over the people who have to use that name later on.

If we named all our streets after Russian leaders, and had Russian leaders on our currency, and our states were named after Russian icons, I think it's safe to say that that would cede power and influence to Russia at America's expense. Assuming Americans in the past understood this principle, and I believe they did, I'm left wondering why they would have done this.

Of course, my second point about discouraging tourism is also relevant.

Comment: There wasn't some underlying, agreed-upon, unanimous strategy over naming locations across the continent. It was ad-hoc, informal, and based very much on local whims. As I stated, it's also incorrect to believe there was some sort of power-play going on. I think that was certainly the case in some regions with some native nations, but that wasn't the case in other places. *All that said, this might be a better question for gis.se or english.se*

Comment: Again, naming a _state_ is a huge thing.  We're not talking about the names they chose for a quarry.

Also, gis.se and english.se don't seem to be appropriate.  I'm not trying to figure out if the names are 100% faithful to the Aboriginal Tribes in question.

Perhaps the question can be rephrased to ask if the Americans were politically foolish to have not Americanized those names.  The question can be stated in two ways.  First, in terms of how things actually worked out, from their point of view.  And second, in terms of the best _theoretical_ political solution, from their point of view.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear what you feel was foolish strategy-wise.

Comment: I tried to be clear in my question.  It would seem to deter tourism and settlement.  It would seem to diminish American political power.  

Conversely, giving them American names would seem to benefit tourism and settlement.  It would also seem to increase augment political power.

Comment: Well, at the time, I don't think Tourism was really a huge thing what with the fact it'd take months to get there and all the dangers of the Oregon Trail and such. As for settlement, they already had programs in place to encourage it. I don't think the marketing of a state name likely played a huge part in that. Remember, this wasn't the epoch of consumerism and disposable income back then. :)

Comment: @Anonymous Whether or not the names could have been chosen to better project power and encourage settlement, at the time there were already well-established names as Bobson has pointed out.  It likely would have required quite a bit of work to persuade people (remember America was a Democracy) to change the name from what they're familiar with.  And it would have required a lot more work to get everyone to agree on a new name.  Name it after a politician and everyone in the opposition party objects.  You want statehood to pass so pick a name that is neutral to the politics of the day.

Comment: @Anonymous I'm very suspicious of the influence you ascribe to the person who names things. I suspect the more important factor is what allowed them to name it in the first place, and the choice of name is mostly inconsequential.

Answer (score 1):

The U.S. states named after aboriginal tribes were states where whites and Indians got along relatively well. Often, these states were "less desirable" land that the whites didn't mind sharing with the Indians. For instance, the "Dakotas" are among the least attractive land in the United States. Americans herded Indians from other, more desirable states like Montana and Wyoming to the Dakotas.

Kentucky was another example. It was named after the Indian "Kaintucke" by Daniel Boone, a white "frenemy" of the Indians. He fought them, but he liked them, and they liked him, more than other white men. It was left alone for some time, because it was a "backwater" for Virginia.

It was the more desirable territories, particularly along the coasts, where whites didn't want to share land with Indians, and preferred European names. That is true for the 13 colonies, and also for Gulf Coast lands like Florida and Louisiana (state).

Comment: -1 since this answer is Just Historically Wrong. [Lacota very explicitly WANTED to move to Dacotas - so much so that they in fact warred with and expelled other tribes to do so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakota_people#History).

Comment: @user4012 In context, desirability is from the perspective of the white man. And at the time I suspect white folks didn't find the Dakotas especially attractive. Heck, they still have low population density.